# How to return bin count from a 2dhistogram

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I have a dataset of xy coordinates that are used to make a scatter plot. I have setup a `2dhistogram` to create a grid that overlays this plot. I want to the bin coordinate when any scatter point is in each bin. The code below displays the scatter plot and highlights the bin when any scatter point is located within it.

Below is an example of what I have thus far:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [random.randrange(1,100,1) for _ in range (10000)]
y = [random.randrange(1,100,1) for _ in range (10000)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(0,100)

bins = [np.linspace(*ax.get_xlim(), 50),
        np.linspace(*ax.get_ylim(), 50)]

zi, xi, yi = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins)
zi = np.ma.masked_equal(zi, 0)

ax.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi.T)    
ax.set_xticks(bins[0], minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(bins[1], minor=True)
ax.grid(True, which='minor')

scat = ax.scatter(x, y, s = 1)
```

This displays the scatter point and highlights the bin it's in. I'm hoping to return the co-ordinate of each a bin when a scatter point is located within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the `x`, `y`, and `bins` to calculate in what bin each (x, y) pair will be located. Basically, look for a sign change between the x and y bins and the (x, y) pair, and this tells us in what bin the point lies.

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def used_bins(x, y, bins):
    bin_idxs = []
    for xelem, yelem in zip(x, y):
        xbin = ((bins[0] - xelem) < 0).sum()
        ybin = ((bins[1] - yelem) < 0).sum()
        bin_idxs.append((xbin, ybin))

    return bin_idxs


x = [random.randrange(1,100,1) for _ in range (10)]
y = [random.randrange(1,100,1) for _ in range (10)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(0,100)

bins = [np.linspace(*ax.get_xlim(), 100),
        np.linspace(*ax.get_ylim(), 50)]

zi, xi, yi = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=bins)
zi = np.ma.masked_equal(zi, 0)

ax.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi.T)    
ax.set_xticks(bins[0], minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(bins[1], minor=True)
ax.grid(True, which='minor')

scat = ax.scatter(x, y, s = 1) 

# compute the x, y bin index for each x,y element
bin_idxs = used_bins(x, y, bins)
```

Sample output:

[(85, 45), (74, 27), (65, 43), (8, 49), (8, 19), (89, 25), (51, 30), (38, 17), (98, 12), (24, 6)]

Comment: Thanks. This is great but I'll have to rearrange my approach. I might have to put this in a new question but is it possible to return a total count of how many times a scatter point is located within each bin. Using your output coordinates, those bins would provide a count of 1 each.

Comment: I will revise the answer with that in mind if you want. Did you mean to make `x` and `y` integers and not real numbers? In this case, the x bin is kind of weird since there are as many possible values and bins (100 values and 100 bins).